# Firebase queries taking forever to execute even though my database is almost empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app in android using Firebase.

In my experience, every task I'm doing, such as Login, getting data with OnDataChanged, etc. is being done in huge delays even though the database is almost empty. when I'm debugging the code, I see that the program flow keeps running and "skipping" the firebase listeners, and then executes them only after the program has achieved a much later state of it. This leads to many race conditions which I'm usually trying to solve with sleeps on the main thread, but that slows my app even more and makes it unstable. as an example I'm posting the code for the LoginActivity below, it uses a UserLoginTask in which I'm calling the Firebase's AuthWithPassword method, and once a auth was successful I'm calling a OnDataChanged method to retrieve the user's data from the database and storing it on MyAppModel which is a singleton model. I'd be very glad if you could look at it and try telling me what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

```
package com.biu.ap2.mysitter;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.AuthData;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;


public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world", "a@a:a"
    };
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private Button mRegisterView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    myAppModel model;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);




        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        //populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mRegisterView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);


        mRegisterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login_btnLogin || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btnLogin);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_btnLogin);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }


            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
       // return email.contains("@");
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
       // return password.length() > 0;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;
        boolean flag = false;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;

        }

        public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        public boolean getFlag() {
            return this.flag;
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(LoginActivity.this);
            final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://mybabysit.firebaseio.com/");
            ref.authWithPassword(mEmail, mPassword, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                    setFlag(true);
                    setUser(mEmail);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.d("blah", firebaseError.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(8000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getFlag())
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {

                try {
                    // Simulate network access.
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, IntroductionActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("email", mEmail);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.failed));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void setUser(final String email) {
        model = model.getInstance();
        final String mEmail=email;
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://mybabysit.firebaseio.com");
        Firebase userRef = ref.child("users");
        //  Firebase uidref=ref.child("uid").child(ref.getAuth().getUid());
        // Attach an listener to read the data at our sitterPosts reference
        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            //ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot UserSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User myUser = UserSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (mEmail.equals(myUser.getEmail()))
                        model.getInstance().setLoggedUser(myUser);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
//*/
```

**Update****:** It seems that the slow response was due to the "SetUser" method inside OnAuthenticate. recieves a bitmap object from the database, and recieving a Bitmap takes a very long while. Removing it from there and compressing the Bitmap to be less heavy made the query almost 5 times faster, a sleep of 3 seconds seems to do the work now.

Thanks you all for the responses!

Comment: Mayby this is causing delay Thread.sleep(8000);

Comment: Also you don't need to set up Firebase in an Async task. Probably unrelated to the issues you're having but still.

Comment: Consider upgrading from Firebase 2.5.x [following the outline in this guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android). Also, [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is deprecated, replaced by `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It seems that the slow response was the "SetUser" method inside OnAuthenticate. recieves a bitmap object from the database, and recieving a Bitmap takes a very long while. Removing it from there and compressing the Bitmap to be less heavy made the query almost 5 times faster, a sleep of just 3 seconds seems to do the work now.

Thanks you all for the responses!